# Trying to code a categorical variable using ifelse() but I can't code more than one category to a variable

Tags: r, data-transform

I am trying to code a single column with multiple categorical variables but the condition that I am using comes from multiple columns. Right now, the dataset looks like:

```
Asian Black White Indigenous
1     0     0     0
0     1     0     0
0     0     1     0
1     0     0     1
0     1     0     0
```

I am trying to code an ethnicity column that identifies the other columns through a 1-4 variable, like this:

```
Asian Black White Indigenous  Race
1     0     0     0           1
0     1     0     0           2
0     0     1     0           3
1     0     0     1           4
0     1     0     0           2
```

I originally tried an ifelse() statement but I would run it for one category and it would delete the values of the other category. I also tried a more traditional if else statement (shown below) but it threw an error stating that the statement was not interpretable as logical.

```
race6 <- race5 %>%
if(asian1 == 1){
  mutate(race == "Asian")
   } else if (black1 == 1){
  mutate(race == "Black")
   } else if (pacific1 == 1){
  mutate(race == "Pacific")
   } else if (white1 == 1){
  mutate(race == "White")
   } else {
  mutate(race == "Other")
 }
```

Is there a way to improve my code (or just make it run)?

Comment: look at `case_when` from the `dplyr` package

Comment: Try `mutate(race = case_when(asian1 == 1 ~ "Asian", ..., TRUE ~ "Other"))`